# How to control CSS pseudo ::before and ::after through CMS depending if text is in the header element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to control the css pseudo classes of an h2 header which normally contains text. The website is built in a CMS and HTML, AND CSS, but when text is removed from the h2 tags, the pseudo elements still appear. I know pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, and I know some of this can be controlled with CSS, but I feel like I may be missing a condition.
      HTML
      
         ::before
           Text
         ::after

```
   CSS
    h2:before, h2:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -87px;
    top: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #cdcdcb;
    }

   ------ text -------- <!-- looks something like this --->
```

Comment: you can't check for DOM content (inside the tags) in a css selector. you'll have to parse through javascript and then add a class if there is text inside

Comment: an idea, if that is not feasible is to add a data-attribute with text=true liek <h2 data-text="true"> blah </h2> css: h2[data-text='true']{ etc. etc. }

Comment: So I will need to target the element, write a condition if text is not present, remove class?

Comment: yeah... unless someone knows of a way, but i'm 95% certain there isn't (hence why its a comment)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Ok I will try adding the data-attribute to the h2 and to the css. Wish me luck!

Comment: though how is the text getting removed from the h2 text?

Comment: By not adding it in the CMS in the Page Title field. That's why I wasn't sure if I needed a condition or if it could be done with javascript. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the height into appropriate % rather than in 'px', your issue will be resolved without any use of javascript.

```
height: 7%;
```

Below is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/n41f366e/

I believe this is what you are expecting.

Use `max-height: 2px;` to set is consistent for all the titles and use `bottom: 0;` for `:before` pseudo element to align the bar to bottom of the title. [updated fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/n41f366e/11/)

Comment: At first when I saw your comment I wasn't sure if that would work because I thought you were making it fluid. But that may actually work. I will keep you posted

Comment: Hi Masoom - I got the desired result in respect to the pseudo elements being removed if there is no title. But when I changed the master CSS file, the psuedo element's sizes look inconsistent and I am not sure if it has to do with the CSS reset. Could you suggest another solution?

Comment: Masoom thanks again that's exactly the property I was missing. Max-height overrides height leaving consistent pseudo elements